# Is it possible for any iPhone Barcode Scanner to scan barcode from web page and pass code back to page?

Tags: iphone, mobile-website, barcode-scanner

Scanning barcode from web page and passing this code back to same page is possible in Android using http://code.google.com/p/zxing/ tool. Android app can be invoked successfully from webpage, scans the barcode and sends to code back to same web-page.

I need exactly same functionality in iPhone. It is an open issue with Zxing :- http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=414&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary

I would like to know if there is any similar app for iPhone  which gives this feature.

Many thanks.

Comment: As this question still being browsed,and earned popular question badge, I would add that ZXing has added support for iPhone too. Latest ZXing version support on iTune Store does this.

Answer (score 0):

As far pre-built Browser Apps go, Browscan is not a bad option.

I stumbled across it the App Store - it's a basic web browser that has a little "Scan" button the user can click at any time.

Dead simple, and works pretty well.
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/browscan-barcode-scanner/id564055630?mt=8